# Spring DataSource bean not autowiring properly

Tags: spring, jdbc, datasource, code-injection

my Spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.test.dao.impl"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.class"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"></property>
    <property name="username" value="test"></property>
    <property name="password" value="testpass"></property>
</bean>
```

my model

```
package org.test.model;

public class User {

private String id;
private String name;
private String password;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

my dao

```
package org.test.dao;

import org.test.model.User;
import java.util.List;
public interface TestInterface {
public List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

my DaoImplementation

```
package org.test.dao.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.test.dao.TestInterface;
import org.test.model.User;
@Component
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface {

public DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    System.out.println(dataSource);
}
@Override
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
            jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST_USERS";
            return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserRowMapper());
}
private class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User>{

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int num) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
        user.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        return user;
    }

}

}
```

my main class

```
package org.test.run;

import java.util.List;

import org.test.dao.impl.TestInterfaceImpl;
import org.test.model.User;

public class Run {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestInterfaceImpl t = new TestInterfaceImpl();
    List<User> users = t.getAllUsers();
    System.out.println(users);
}

}
```

ERROR I M GETTING

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at      o     `enter code here`rg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:99     )
at    `enter code here`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
at org.test.dao.impl.TestInterfaceImpl.getAllUsers(TestInterfaceImpl.java:35)
at org.test.run.Run.main(Run.java:15)
```

Whenever i am trying to inject datasource, its not working. I don't know what went wrong. all the configuration is in place. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your db url doesn't look right, should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`, yours seems like a combination of oracle and mysql, also normally the driver name is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` without the `class`

Comment: Try to add `@Qualifier("myDataSource")` to the `@AutoWired` setter method.

Answer (score -1):

The DAO implementation class needs to be marked for handling by spring:

```
@Repository
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface {}
```

Now if spring package scanning is being used, it will find this class and process all the @Autowired annotations.

Although it's not necessary, but try adding `@Qualifier` annotation to you datasource setter method.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    System.out.println(dataSource);
}
```

Annotating your DAO class `@Repository` will resolve the issues. You can provide identifier to your dao class by making the annotation `@Repository("testInterfaceImpl")`.